# According to basic oop conventions, should the menu code be in the main method or in a class?

Tags: java, oop

I'm a student and I'm new to Java, this assignment I am doing is the first assignment I have to do that has to strictly follow oop conventions. So this may be a newb question. When coding a menu, would it be appropriate to put the menu code in the main method or should it be in a class and instantiated along with everything else?

EDIT:
The menu menu is a simple command line menu that is inputed with numbers, no gui. Not that far yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to strictly follow the OOP convention you could have your own class like

```
abstract class MenuItem {
  int index;

  protected MenuItem(int index) {
    this.index = index;
  }

  abstract void action();
}

class ExitMenuItem {
  ExitMenuItem() {
    super(3); // the index value of the menu item
  }

  void action() {
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

So that you can have a subclass specific for every menu item that has its behavior.

Then you could have a menu container, something like:

```
class Menu {
  ArrayList<MenuItem> items;

  void executeAction(String input) {
    ..
  }
}
```

that should understand which voice has been chosen according to the stdin input and execute it. Of course you can enrich everything by having a default text for every menu item and whatever. Then in your main method you just instantiate the menu and take care of forwarding stdin input to it.

Mind that this is usually overkill in a simple menu but if you want to understand OOP then it's a nice way to go.

Comment: Actually I'm just talking about a simple numbered menu in console text.

Comment: No problem, it was my fault I did not include that detail.

Comment: You can instantiate them as instance variables that gets instantiated as soon as the class containing it is instantiated or you can instantiate them in a static block but going through main is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

For a Object-Oriented approach, you should create the menu in the specific class. Main method is a legacy of Procedural/Imperative programming languages. Main method should just run the main thread.

Comment: So in other words only instantiation should take place in the main method? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, basically your main method should be used only as a class loader.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  That's usually the worst answer one can provide, but unfortunately, it fits perfectly.

You haven't provided the full requirements so it is a little difficult to guess what you are intending.  Is this menu specific to a single class?  Can it be run multiple times?  Should it be able to be run in parallel?

Or rather, is this menu just an entry point into the actual program? ex: press 1 to login, press 2 to display something on screen, press 3 for ....

The reason I am giving you these questions is because they will shape the structure of your code.  In the first case, if they are menus related specifically to a class and can be run from multiple locations in the code at multiple points, then it would make sense that the belong within the class structure itself (non static).

However, if the menu is purely an entry point into the application, it would make sense to either put them in the main() section of the code, or code another static method called menu() for clarity.  But realistically, the menu() method would only get called from the main.

The next thing to ask yourself is how you plan to validate the responses from the menu selection.  Do you need complicated/involved code?  Does it make more sense for the validation routines to be part of the main method or have their own methods?  Does it make more sense to have member variables to communicate between method class to validate, etc?

Keep in mind that static methods can be called without instantiating the class.  That being said, a static  main() method or static menu() method still remain within the class itself, and are part of OOP design.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself this - if putting codes that prints menu in the main method,  how do I handle printing multiple times?

If putting codes into methods in the same class as the main and I need to print menu somewhere else probably in another main class, how do I handle that?

Eventually, you will have a class that handles code dealing with displaying of menu, and the main class would only be calling on methods of that class. :)

Answer (score -1):

Probably there are different tastes to this, and a good answer might also depend on what your app is doing.

First, for a small application I wouldn't mind having the menu in the main class.

But then for nice structure, it is a good idea to have a class that is responsible for printing the line-based menu and then of course also for reading the user input and invoking the action the user asks for. I think a good idea would be to call such a class `Controller` or `Dispatcher`. This class would be a singleton. Further I would think it's a good idea
to have a method `displayMenu` and `dispatch`. Both would be called from the constructor consecutively.

How `dispatch` is then calling the appriopriate action will depend on the rest of your app.

Some people don't like this style, as your main routine will probably have declarations only.